# Assinging null to a variable of nullable type

Tags: c#, nullable, implicit-conversion, assignment-operator

You can assign a null to a nullable type variable like so:

```
bool? b = null
```

`Nullable<T>` is a value type so I assumed that this was done by overloading implicit conversion.

Here is the implementation taken from the .NET framework source code:

```
 public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
        return new Nullable<T>(value);
    }
```

The type parameter `T` is restricted to a `struct`. So the argument `value` is restricted to value types and cannot be null.

I would like to know how and where the null assignment is handled.